# Looking for a query solution

Tags: mysql

I need help with a query solution

table: roomclimate

| id | time | deviceId | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-22 15:49:31 | 1 | 23.5 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-12-22 15:49:31 | 2 | 10.5 | 50 |
| 3 | 2021-12-22 15:59:31 | 1 | 23.5 | 56 |
| 4 | 2021-12-22 15:59:31 | 2 | 10.7 | 57 |

and now i want to group the values like this

| time | dev_1_temp | dev_1_humi | dev_2_temp | dev_2_humi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-22 15:49:31 | 23.5 | 50 | 10.5 | 50 |
| 2021-12-22 15:59:31 | 23.5 | 56 | 10.7 | 57 |

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Search for mysql pivot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: thank for your answers! pivot is the soloution and  i din't  remember me at this..

Answer (score 1):

So, this is working.. but is there an better Solution?

```sql
SELECT
    `time`,

    MAX(IF(`deviceId`=1,ROUND(`temperature`,1),NULL)) AS dev_1_temp,
    MAX(IF(`deviceId`=1,`humidity`,NULL)) AS dev_1_humi,
    MAX(IF(`deviceId`=2,ROUND(`temperature`,1),NULL)) AS dev_2_temp,
    MAX(IF(`deviceId`=2,`humidity`,NULL)) AS dev_2_humi
 

FROM tbl_klima
GROUP BY `time` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT
    base.time,
    dev1.temperature, dev1.humidity,
    dev2.temperature, dev2.humidity
FROM roomclimate AS base
LEFT JOIN roomclimate AS dev1
    ON dev1.time = base.time AND dev1.deviceId = 1
LEFT JOIN roomclimate AS dev2
    ON dev2.time = base.time AND dev2.deviceId = 2
ORDER BY base.time DESC
```

I hope that you have an index on `time`.

Comment: Thank you, this is working too.. but i have to  change "ORDER BY" to "GROUP BY"

Comment: @markus_he. I had to think some seconds why you need `GROUP BY`. It's because there are several rows in `base` with the same `time`. Did you notice any difference in speed between your solution and mine?